# How to support dynamic type in labels in iOS 7?

Tags: dynamic, types, uilabel, uitextview, ios7

How do I support Dynamic Type in `UILabel` and `UITextView` in iOS 7? I'm adapting one of our projects for iOS 7 and would like to support this accessibility feature. I can't find the specific how to tutorial on it on Apple's iOS Developer site.

Comment: Check this tutorial [How to Support Dynamic Type in iOS 7 Apps.](http://mythoughtsandexperiments.blogspot.in/2013/12/how-to-support-dynamic-type-in-ios-7.html)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you use the new `UIFont` methods then you're pretty much there - you just need to add the observer to listen for changes.

Rather than setting a specific font size, you should use the `preferredFontForTextStyle:` and related methods when styling your labels (if you're using Interface Builder you can select a style directly in the inspector). For example:

`self.label.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];`

Once you've done that you should listen for the `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification`. When you receive this notification you should layout your labels to support the newly selected size (if you're using autolayout this is normally as simple as sending `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` to your views).

If you're looking for official documentation then take a look at the [Text Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH4-SW65).

Comment: Is there not a way to access the style that was picked in Interface Builder? If not, that seems like a big oversight. Now I have to set it in 2 places, which means it will inevitably get out of sync.

Comment: `preferredFontForTextStyle` returns a system font though, is there any way to do this with custom fonts?

Comment: @kevin: `UIFontMetrics` class can scale any custom font according to the current font metrics: [UIFontMetrics documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontmetrics)

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3 and iOS 10 you can use

```
headline.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
headline.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
```

See [this excellent post](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/auto-adjusting-fonts-for-dynamic-type/) for more information, especially how to support pre iOS 10.