# How to use Xcode5 new "Text styles" functionality

Tags: ios, xcode5, text-formatting

I was editing the 57 xibs in my huge project, because of a complete recast due to ios7 update.

I was editing one by one each label when I saw this:

[image: styles]

A way to define an unique style for each label, with some predefined styles!

But impossible to modify nor add/remove them. And no more info on the web!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Support Dynamic Type in Labels in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092277/how-to-support-dynamic-type-in-labels-in-ios-7)

Comment: See also: http://www.peterboni.net/blog/2013/06/29/ios-7-dynamic-type/

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. My question is more about the Interface Builder part.

Comment: Selecting "Body" is the same as `self.myLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];`.  There's nothing else in Interface Builder.

Comment: Ok, so there's no way to edit/add/remove the font styles, if I understand.

Comment: You cannot define your own styles in Interface Builder.  You can programmatically using UIFontDescriptor.

Comment: Ok, thanks. i will document myself on it. I'd better close this thread.